Ubuntu 24.04 is hangs on Invalid ELF header magic != JELF during boot
Briefly, I added some software and did some regular work on my laptop today. When I restarted, bootup started hanging after a line saying [6.626136] Invalid ELF header magic: !=JELF (^ above the J). I let the computer sit for approximately an hour and nothing changed. Any help resolving this issue would be much appreciated.
OS:
I can't boot into ubuntu proper, but I'm sure these are my statistics:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (64 bit), with Gnome Flashback Metacity Gnome Version 11
Linux Kernal Version: 6.8.0-45-generic NOTE: /home and /root are on different partitions.
It is a duel boot system with Grub version 2.12 and windows 11. I installed the Ubuntu OS September 1st as my primary use os and it has been working great until today (Sept 18th). I ran an apt update and upgrade. Then installed several applications, Arduino IDE through gnome software center, and the rest through the command line. Using apt: espeak, openjdk-11-jdk, libopenjfx-java, font-manager, artha, foliate, tilix, dict, and festival. Flatpak: Speech Note, Font Downloader. Snap: rpi-imager. dpkg: BlueJ-linux-x64-540.deb
I also had added several add-ons for Freecad, but these were local changes.
Computer: Asus Vivobook, 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700H   2.30 GHz, 16 GB RAM
Details:
Ubuntu loads all the way to Started gdm.services Gnome Display Manager (marked OK). I have fsck scheduled for so many reboots, and the fsckd-cancel came between gdm and the invalid Elf header. I edited the ubuntu boot options in grub from quiet to verbose, and nothing new printed before this line. The last thing listed in the boot.log is Finished msystem-backlight which finished ok. I was also unable to boot Ubuntu with linux 6.8.0-41/25-generic under Advanced Options for Ubuntu in grub but could load recovery mode. Windows boots normally.
Similar to: U 20.04 At Boot Error Invalid ELF header magic != JELF
Differences: Could not boot generic nor did boot-repair fix.
Preliminary Steps: I booted a live CD and did disk checks on /root and /home using fsck -f, disks, and gparted and found no errors. I loaded boot-repair and repaired grub and checked the disks, but this did not altar the behavior. (grub report https://paste.debian.net/hidden/3c5b7088).
Under recovery-mode, I ran (as root) apt upgrade --fix-missing, apt update/upgrade, apt install --reinstall linux-headers-generic, apt clean, and apt autoclean.
No changes.

When it freezes can you get a terminal? Ctl + Alt + F2 or just Alt F2. It may ask you for a command. Try gnome-terminal. Then follow instructions from here. https://medium.com/@sundharwinston/ubuntu-graphical-user-interface-gui-not-working-e7ea95f2b24a

Sorry better is CTL + ALT + F3. It should give you a terminal login screen.  ( & CTL + ALT + F1) gets you back.

Thanks for the commands and resource. They helped out. I actually poured through the apt and dpkg history logs and found that Etcher had installed Fuse as a dependency and for some reason when Fuse was installing apt uninstalled gnome-flashback, the ubuntu's (nolonger unity window's system), nautilus, and a whole lot more. I was able reinstall them through the command line and it seems to work. Thanks for the help and quick response.
